# How to built multiple one-to-one relationship with jHipster JDL?

Tags: jhipster

Consider the following :

```
relationship OneToOne{
    Person{family} to Family{husband}
}

relationship OneToOne{
    Person{family} to Family{wife}
}
```

This will create two family variables in the Person Class. What is the correct way to declare this kind of relationship ?

The only hack I see, is to name the variables in Person: family1 family2, and then get the non null in one getFamily getter. But was wondering if there is cleaner way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Since a family is a group of Persons you need one to many bidirectional relationship between Person and Family

```
relationship OneToMany{
    Person{family(familyName)} to Family{familyMember(firstName)}
}
```

Since this relationship is bidirectional (for more info read jhipster doc for  [bidirectional one-to-many relationship](https://jhipster.github.io/managing-relationships/#1)) there is no need for defining opposite direction too.

```
  1      2        3
Person{family(familyName)}
```

Here

1. Object name
2. Variable name in that object
3. The value that you want to
   be displayed in html page when selecting family, if you leave this
   empty in this case family id will be used in comboboxes which is not
   a user friendly way

Comment: The objective was to have 2 variables "Person husband", "Person wife" instead of Set. That is possible if I manually tweak the getters. But I was wondering if it is supported in jHipster.

Comment: Sory for misunderstanding I see what you need. I would use another object like FamilyMember which contains a person and role of person in this relationship. Then create one to many relation between family and FamilyMember. Set role for husband and husband himself in that member object and add it to family but again need tweak the getters. maybe?

Comment: I thought of that, but 2 variable make it easier in other part of the app.  Sorry can't accept the answer but will up vote! Thank you.

Answer (score -2):

The following could work:

```
relationship OneToOne{
    Family to Person{husband},
    Family to Person{wife},
    Person to Family
}
```